# Add total of multiple counted columns

Tags: mysql

So I have a database where I have managed to count the number of IDs for each column and given them a easier to see name. using the query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT( Club_Id ) AS Club_membership, 
COUNT( Founder_Id ) AS Clubs_ounded, 
COUNT( Host_Id ) AS events_Hosted, 
COUNT( Attendee_Id ) AS attended, 
person_Id
FROM Social_Points
GROUP BY person_Id

output:

Club_membership | Clubs_founded  | events_hosted  | attended | person_ID  |
----------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+
          0     |          1     |          1     |    20    |     111    |
          2     |          0     |          0     |    16    |     222    |
          1     |          0     |          1     |    3     |     333    |
          3     |          0     |          0     |    20    |     444    |
```

I would like to have a column after "person_ID" that sums up the four other column
Like this:

```
Club_membership | Clubs_founded  | events_hosted  | attended | person_ID  |  total  |
----------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+---------+
          0     |          1     |          1     |    20    |     111    |   22    |
          2     |          0     |          0     |    16    |     222    |   18    |
          1     |          0     |          1     |    3     |     333    |   5     |
          3     |          0     |          0     |    20    |     444    |   23    |
```

Is this possible? Or should I just call it a loss and write another solution in my report?

Comment: If you add `COUNT(*)` at the end, what will happen?

Comment: I'm curious how the table `Social_Points` looks like.. the structure and row data that end up with the result you're currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, although it is not pretty

```
SELECT 
COUNT( Club_Id ) AS Club_membership, 
COUNT( Founder_Id ) AS Clubs_ounded, 
COUNT( Host_Id ) AS events_Hosted, 
COUNT( Attendee_Id ) AS attended, 
person_Id,
COUNT( Club_Id ) + COUNT( Founder_Id ) + COUNT( Host_Id ) + COUNT( Attendee_Id ) as total
FROM Social_Points
GROUP BY person_Id
```

Comment: This did the trick. At this point in my report I don't care how messy it looks

Comment: Glad it helped then!